# Why is Ansible unable to read unicode string as JSON?

Tags: json, ansible, yaml, jinja2

### Summary

When retrieving data using the uri module in Ansible, I am unable to parse a section of it as JSON to retrieve a nested value.

The desired value is the `ci` field inside the `content.data` or `json.data` field (see **output** below).

### Steps to Reproduce

**site.yml**

```
--- 
- hosts: localhost 
  gather_facts: false 
  tasks: 
    - name: Get String 
      uri: 
        url: "http://localhost/get-data" 
        method: POST 
        body_format: json 
        body: "{ \"kong-jid\": \"run-sn-discovery\" }"
        return_content: yes 
      register: output 

    - set_fact:
        ci: "{{ output.json.data.ci }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ci }}"
```

**The {{ output }} variable**

```
{
  u'status': 200, 
  u'cookies': {}, 
  u'url': u'http://kong-demo:8000/get-data', 
  u'transfer_encoding': u'chunked', 
  u'changed': False, 
  u'connection': u'close', 
  u'server': u'kong/0.34-1-enterprise-edition', 
  u'content': 
  u'{"data":"\\"{u\'ci\': u\'3bb8d625dbac3700e4f07b6e0f96195b\'}\\""}', 
  'failed': False, 
  u'json': {u'data': u'"{u\'ci\': u\'3bb8d625dbac3700e4f07b6e0f96195b\'}"'}, 
  u'content_type': u'application/json', 
  u'date': u'Thu, 18 Apr 2019 15:50:25 GMT', 
  u'redirected': False, 
  u'msg': u'OK (unknown bytes)'
}
```

**Result**

```
[user@localhost]$ ansible-playbook site.yml
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: all

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Pass Redis data to next task as output] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'ci'

The error appears to have been in 'site.yml': line 19, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - set_fact:
      ^ here

exception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>
exception: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'ci'
```

### Important Troubleshooting Information

It appears the root issue is related to which Ansible type being interpreted.  I desire to parse `ci` from the output in one task.

***The two-task solution shown below works, but this leads me to believe this should be possible in one line...***

**Two-Task Solution**

```
- set_fact:
    ci: "{{ output.json.data | from_json }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ ci['ci'] }}"
```

But the `ci` fact set from `{{ output.json.data | from_json }}` reports a different TYPE than the inline type...

**Unicode or Dict?**

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ output.json.data | from_json | type_debug }}" # returns unicode

- set_fact:
    ci: "{{ output.json.data | from_json }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ ci | type_debug }}" # returns dict
```

**Why isn't `{{ output.json.data | from_json | type_debug }}`

the same as `{{ ci | type_debug }}`?**

Answer (score 0):

Although `json` and `data` are keys in their resp objects, `ci` is just part of a larger string (which happens to look like a JSON object

If the relevant line in your datastructure would be:

```
u'json': {u'data': {'ci': u'3bb8d625dbac3700e4f07b6e0f96195b'}},
```

then you could expect to use `"{{ output.json.data.ci }}"` but not when the `.ci` part is just a normal part of a string.

Comment: How can I turn that string into a json object?  I would expect using the `from_json` filter on that string would allow me to get it, but doing so returns an error.  `{{ (output.json.data | from_json)['ci'] }}` returns `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'ci'`

Comment: I think the result of `output.json.data` is quoted, and assume you would need to get rid of the start and end-quote before piping through `| from_json`. No idea though on how to do that (i.e. whether you can use unix commands like `tr` to do so)

Comment: Getting rid of the quotes didn't seem to have any effect on the data structure, unfortunately.  It seems buggy that the types are different one line away from each other - one allows normal extraction of the ci variable and the other chokes despite the structure of the filters.